# NameError: name 'greater_less_equal_5' is not defined

Tags: python

i am doing a python tutorial at codecademy and i am stuck at I Got 99 Problems, But a Switch Ain't One and i get an error NameError: name 'greater_less_equal_5' is not defined

```
def greaterlessequal_5(answer):
    if answer > 5 :
        return 1
    elif answer > 5:

        return -1
    else:
        return 0

print greaterlessequal5(4) 
print greaterlessequal5(5)
print greaterlessequal_5(6)
```

what should i do?

Comment: since you only defined the `greaterlessequal_5` function, this is the only one you can call...

Comment: aditionally the error you actually probably recieve is `greaterlessequal5 is not defined`  (it really helps us help you if you put your actual error messages and code,just copy and paste dont try to type it from memory)

Comment: i didn't type from memory

Comment: NameError: name 'greaterlesequal5' is not defined this is the error

Comment: Not the cause of your `NameError` (which has already been adequately resolved above, I believe), but I do believe you should also check for issues with your if conditions.  Seems you got something backward there.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about noticing that you have extra underscores.


Comment: I just checked on codeAcademy for that problem, and what you posted doesn't match what they have. Perhaps reload the problem there?

Comment: i tried that at first but still the same

Comment: Pines how do you spell  greaterlessequal5()

Comment: i put it to greaterlessequal5() then what

Comment: go to http://www.codecademy.com/courses/python-beginner-BxUFN/3/4?curriculum_id=4f89dab3d788890003000096#

Comment: yes i know CDspace but still says NameError: name 'greater_less_equal_5' is not defined

Answer (score 2):

There are three problems with the code:

- greaterlesequal5() is not defined
- greaterlessequal5() is not defined [both these are typos]
- Your `if` and your `elif` both test the same condition. `elif` should probably be looking for `answer < 5`

Comment: tried that same error

Comment: As CDspace pointed out, you changed the code given to you by CodeAcademy. Guido himself could have written a piece of code to test if a number was greater, less than or equal to five, but if his code didn't use a function named precisely greater_less_equal_5() then he would have got the same error as you. When you submit your answer to codeacademy, the interpreter tests the code by calling the function with a number of arguments you don't see. If the name of the function has been changed, a syntax error results, even for otherwise perfectly formed code.

Answer (score 1):

Click "Reset Code" on that problem on codeAcademy.com and try again. Your posted code does not match the code from the site, as below.

```
def greater_less_equal_5(answer):
    if 
        return 1
    elif          
        return -1
    else:
        return 0

print greater_less_equal_5(4)
print greater_less_equal_5(5)
print greater_less_equal_5(6)
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because greater_less_equal_5 is not defined
Also using the same if condtion